# Create a list of district values from multiple documents and a count using MongoDB and an aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregate

I have number of customer document in MongoDB (community 5.3.1), each with an array of Vehicle objects. I'm trying to pull a district list of Makes, Models, Transmission Type etc from all the customers along with a total for each make using a MongoDB aggregate.

I'm part way there with the following:

```
   [
    {
      '$match': {
        // this stage just pulls all the customer documents together
      }
    }, {
      '$unwind': {
        'path': '$Vehicles'
      }
    }, {
      '$group': {
        '_id': null, 
        'makes': {
          '$addToSet': '$Vehicles.Manufacturer'
        },
        'models': {
          '$addToSet': '$Vehicles.Model'
        }, 
        'minPrice': {
          '$min': '$Vehicles.Price'
        }, 
        'maxPrice': {
          '$max': '$Vehicles.Price'
        }, 
        'transmission': {
          '$addToSet': '$Vehicles.Transmission'
        }
      }
    }
  ]
```

This give me my distinct list of Makes, but I can't work out how to get a total of each make.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If group by `$Vehicles.Manufacturer`, not null,  then you can count documents in each group

Comment: Sorry. I've amended the original post. I'm grouping by other things too.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it using a $facet stage. If anybody is interested:

```
  '$facet': {
    'makes': [
      {
        '$group': {
          '_id': '$Vehicles.Manufacturer', 
          'count': {
            '$sum': 1
          }
        }
      }
    ], 
    'models': [
      {
        '$group': {
          '_id': '$Vehicles.Model', 
          'count': {
            '$sum': 1
          }
        }
      }
    ], 
    'tranmission': [
      {
        '$group': {
          '_id': '$Vehicles.Transmission', 
          'count': {
            '$sum': 1
          }
        }
      }
    ], 
    'fuel': [
      {
        '$group': {
          '_id': '$Vehicles.FuelType', 
          'count': {
            '$sum': 1
          }
        }
      }
    ], 
    'body': [
      {
        '$group': {
          '_id': '$Vehicles.BodyType', 
          'count': {
            '$sum': 1
          }
        }
      }
    ], 
    'metadata': [
      {
        '$group': {
          '_id': null, 
          'minPrice': {
            '$min': '$Vehicles.Price'
          }, 
          'maxPrice': {
            '$max': '$Vehicles.Price'
          }, 
          'minEngine': {
            '$min': '$Vehicles.CC'
          }, 
          'maxEngine': {
            '$max': '$Vehicles.CC'
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```